# Problem while importing mysql backup

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1005

While I'm trying to import mysql backup file i receive such an error,

```
ALTER TABLE `sf_guard_group_permission`  ADD CONSTRAINT `sf_guard_group_permission_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY ( `group_id` ) REFERENCES `sf_guard_group` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
ADD CONSTRAINT `sf_guard_group_permission_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY ( `permission_id` ) REFERENCES `sf_guard_permission` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

MySQL zwrócił komunikat: Dokumentacja

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'jezykownia.#sql-1394_72' (errno: 121)
```

Although everything seems to work fine, but it scares me a bit what consequences might
appear in future

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

This thread might help, either there's a foreign key conflict* or there's some old data inside the InnoDB data dictionary.

[This forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,33999,76181#msg-76181) might help and the comments to the [error code reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html) are interesting (search for '121').

Sam

*I didn't know this but they have to be unique in a database.